# OSMNX Looping with geocoder

Tags: python-3.x, openstreetmap, osmnx

What would be the best way to loop through a list of addresses using `geocoder.geocode` if there are some locations that don't exist on the map? How could I skip them so that the loop continues without  this exception? `Exception: Nominatim geocoder returned no results for query "Beli manastir planina,Bakar,Croatia"` 
Below is what I have tried.

```
L = [location1, location2, location3, ..., location n]
KO = []
for l in L:
    KO = list(ox.geocoder.geocode(l))
    if Exception:
        continue
    KO.append(KO)
```

Also I tried this:

```
try: 
    KO = []
    for l in L:
         KO = list(ox.geocoder.geocode(l))
         KO.append(KO)
except Exception:
    pass
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the second snippet. I get no results and no errors. Here is and example of the L list `L = ['Pazinska,Zagreb,Croatia','Pulska, Pazin,Croatia','Zadarska,Zagreb,Croatia','Pazinska,Pula,Croatia']`    The second location doesn't exist and should be skipped. Theoretically

Comment: I think the result of that loop should be a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your for loop and try/except differently. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

locations= ['Pazinska,Zagreb,Croatia',
            'Pulska, Pazin,Croatia',
            'Zadarska,Zagreb,Croatia',
            'Pazinska,Pula,Croatia']

coords = []
for location in locations:
    try: 
        coords.append(ox.geocoder.geocode(location))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```